Why is chrome://inspect not listing the remote target, and how can I resolve this issue so that the target appears in chrome://inspect as expected?
chrome://inspect Not Identifying Remote Target, But devtoolsFrontendUrl Works:
I'm having trouble getting Chrome's chrome://inspect page to recognize a remote target for a Node.js debugger. Here's the situation:
Node.js Debugger Setup:
I'm running a Node.js application with the debugger enabled on port 9229. My setup includes Docker, and the relevant part of the docker-compose.yaml is configured as follows:
abc-server:
  container_name: abc-server
  restart: on-failure
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: node-server/Dockerfile
  command: sh -c "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 server.js"
  ports:
    - "9229:9229"

Issue:
Despite this, the chrome://inspect page does not list the remote target. I've verified that localhost:9229 is correctly added under the Configure... settings in Chrome.
Workaround:
When I directly navigate to the devtoolsFrontendUrl provided in the curl response, the DevTools opens and works as expected.
Steps I've Tried:

Clearing Chrome's cache.
Disabling all extensions and using incognito mode.
Ensuring no firewall or security software is blocking the connection.
Verifying that localhost:9229 is correctly configured in Chrome's Configure... settings.


Solution 1: Configure Target Discovery Settings to include 127.0.0.1:9229
Step 1: Open Chrome Developer Tools
Open Chrome and navigate to any page. Press F12 or right-click on the page and select Inspect to open the Developer Tools.
Step 2: Navigate to chrome://inspect
Type chrome://inspect in the Chrome address bar and press Enter.
Step 3: Access Target Discovery Settings
Click on the Configure... button under the "Discover network targets" section.
Step 4: Add Specific Port
Add 127.0.0.1:9229 in the configuration box to explicitly direct Chrome to look for debugger instances running on localhost at port 9229.
Step 5: Save and Test
Click Done to save the settings. The Node.js application running with --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 should now appear under the "Remote Target" section.

Solution 2: Use a Different Port
If adjusting the discovery settings doesn't work or if you suspect port conflicts, try using a different port.
Step 1: Change the Debugger Port
Modify your Node.js application startup command to use a different port, for example, 9228:
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9228 app.js


Solution 3: Close Conflicting Adobe Applications
Adobe and Creative Cloud applications have been known to use port 9229, which can prevent Chrome from accessing this port for debugging purposes.
Step 1: Identify and Close Adobe Applications
Use Activity Monitor on macOS or Task Manager on Windows to identify and close any running Adobe and Creative cloud processes/services.
Step 2: Retry chrome://inspect
After closing the Adobe applications, go back to chrome://inspect in Chrome.
Step 3: Reconfigure if Necessary
If the port was previously blocked, you might need to re-enter 127.0.0.1:9229 in the Configure... settings under the "Discover network targets" section.
Step 4: Test the Debugger Connection
Try connecting to the debugger again to see if the issue has been resolved by freeing up the port.
